# Python Zeep XML - 0 float value changes type shape

Tags: python, xml, soap, wsdl, zeep

I have a simple type in a XSD

```xml
<xs:element name="RateByRoom">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="BuyingPrice" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="SellingPrice" type="xs:double"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but when I parse

```xml
<HostingRate hosting_type_code="TEST_01:01">
    <RateByRoom>
      <BuyingPrice>0.0</BuyingPrice>
   </RateByRoom>
</HostingRate>
```

I get

```py
{
    'hosting_type_code': 'TEST_01:01',
    'length_of_stay': None
}
```

**Do you think it's an issue specific to my project, or there is something about this I missed in the doc?**

If I change the 0.0 in a 1.0, I get

```py
{
    'hosting_type_code': 'TEST_01:01',
    'length_of_stay': None,
    'RateByRoom': {
        'BuyingPrice': 1.0,
        'SellingPrice': None
    },
    'RatesByPax': None,
    'RatesByOccupancy': None
}
```

Edit: For parsing, I use the following:

```py
response_element: lxml.etree._Element = ...
InventoryUpdate = broker_client.zeep_client.get_element("ns0:InventoryUpdate")
inventory_update = InventoryUpdate.parse(response_element, zeep_client)
```

In this case, `InventoryUpdate` is a high level return type in the WSDL. Then I access elements using the zeep API (attribute or dict syntax), `HostingRate` is somewhere is the tree.

Comment: Please share your code. How do you parse?